# GraphAPI returns BadGateway for Teams App Unistall call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We use the GraphAPI to unistall the Teams app for a user.
It works for some tenant, for other - it doesn't.
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/820b339e-5fbd-404e-a37f-fc0813689c83/teamwork/installedApps/ODIwYjMzOWUtNWZiZC00MDRlLWEzN2YtZmMwODEzNjg5YzgzIyMzMmQ1ODYxZi0xYmQxLTRjZDEtOTE5Yi1iZDdjNTA4MWIzNjY=

It returns the following error without any additionall details:
*Code: BadGateway

Message: Failed to execute backend request.

Inner error:

AdditionalData:

date: 2022-01-12T10:04:08

request-id: ffa520f4-b6ef-485d-811f-cc92e2e490a9

client-request-id: ffa520f4-b6ef-485d-811f-cc92e2e490a9

ClientRequestId: ffa520f4-b6ef-485d-811f-cc92e2e490a9*

We use the Net SDK to GraphAPI to send the request. Looks everything is OK with request as it is successfully executed for some tenant, for other - it doesn't. All required permissions are granted in Azure AD app.

Is it possible to check more error details for request-id: ffa520f4-b6ef-485d-811f-cc92e2e490a9 on Microsoft side?

Comment: @vshandra -
ODataExceptionFilter is handling an exception. Exception type: AppIsTenantAdminPreinstalled. Exception details: Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.Exceptions.ProviderException: Trying to RemoveUserAppEntitlement for an App that is explicitly preinstalled by the tenant admin.
   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Provider.Apps.AppDefinitionItemExtensions.<ValidateIfAppIsAdminPreinstalled>d__48.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\Source\Provider\Provider\Apps\ObjectExtensions\AppDefinitionItemExtensions.cs:line 1638

Comment: @vshandra - It seems you are trying to remove preInstalled app which is preInstalled by Admin.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thanks, it is correct. We also thoughts about it. 
We had 2 tenants where app is preinstalled via Global policy in Teams admin center. For 1 tenant it doesn't work, for another it works.
Looks the reason why it is wroking in another tenant is that user installed app manually prior the global policy was applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to remove preInstalled app which is preInstalled by Admin.
Below is the internal error:

> ODataExceptionFilter is handling an exception. Exception type:
> AppIsTenantAdminPreinstalled. Exception details:
> Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.Exceptions.ProviderException:
> Trying to RemoveUserAppEntitlement for an App that is explicitly
> preinstalled by the tenant admin.    at
> Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Provider.Apps.AppDefinitionItemExtensions.d__48.MoveNext()
> in
> D:\a_work\1\s\Source\Provider\Provider\Apps\ObjectExtensions\AppDefinitionItemExtensions.cs:line
> 1638